# Is there any way to update the reference of each object in the JVM heap?

Tags: java, jvm

Suppose I have the following code:

```java
    public class Main {
      public static String foo;

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main.foo = new String("a");
        String a = Main.foo;

        Main.foo = new String("b");
        // TODO update a's reference

        String b = Main.foo;
      }
    }
```

which instantiates a static variable called `foo` with `new String("a");` and then assigns that to variable `a`. Then, it re-inits `foo` with `new String("b");` and assigns that to variable `b`. At this point and as expected, `a` and `b` "point" to different `Main.foo`: `a` points to a previous version of `Main.foo` and `b` points to the most recent version of `Main.foo`.

Although the code is working as expected, I would like to automatically update the reference of `a` and `b` every single time `Main.foo` is modified. I.e., every time the static variable `Main.foo` is modified, the reference of variables `a` and `b` must be updated and point to the most recent value.

Please note that I have no control over the source code. Therefore, any proposed solution may have to involve bytecode instrumentation or any other solution that does not require any change in the source code.

Would something like `toAddress/fromAddress` from `sun.misc.Unsafe` class be worth exploring? Would I need to go even deeper and use Java Native Interface (JNI)? Or perhaps, I would need to instrument the code and implement something like the [proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) or the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not possible. `a` and `b` don't point to `foo` at all. They just retrieve an object reference from `foo`. It's indistinguishable afterwards, as far as I know.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what you mean when you say you can't modify the source code. What can you modify?

Comment: Note, at no time do ```a``` or ```b``` point to any ```Main.foo```.  After execution of ```a = Main.foo```, ```a``` points to what ```Main.foo``` points to (which is an instance of a String whose value is "a").

Comment: It's unclear to me, however, what the point of all this is.

Comment: There is no sense in writing `new String("a")` or `new String("b")`. Just write `"a"` or `"b"`. Besides that, to understand that particular variables were assigned from a specific field, you would have to analyze the entire code, tracking every data movement. In the worst case, it would include the JRE code and the code of all 3rd party libraries used in that code. Just consider `String someVariable = Arrays.asList(null, "foo", "bar", "baz", Main.foo).subList(2, 4).get(2);` Does `someVariable` relate to `Main.foo` or not?